# Алгоритмы работы с GPS

Tags: android, java, gps

Добрый день.

Пишу программу для отрисовки траектории маршрута на простом View. Т.е. без карт. 
Столкнулся с тем, что даже если стоишь на месте данные GPS довольно сильно скачут (включая скорость).
Сам пока придумал только заносить в маршрут точки с низким значением Acuracy, но при таком подходе в городе можно вообще маршрут не записать.

Собственно хотел узнать, как выходят из данного положения в подобного рода программах. 
Т.е. понятно, что точность GPS не увеличить, но возможно существуют алгоритмы обработки данных, хитрые способы их отображения и т.д.

Данные GPS получаю через LocationListener.onLocationChange. Мое устройство не поддерживает стандарт NMEA.

Comment: как вариант, можно запускать таймер с промежутком, например, в 10 секунд и писать только эти данные, это то, что пришло в голову

Comment: можно записывать перемещения только на расстояния более чем Х метров. то есть отсеивать мелкие колебания. Но это опять же упирается в точность GPS. Не знаю, какие у вас там колебания, но у меня при 8 подключенных спутниках точность +- 3м.

Answer (score 5):

Это известная проблема. В целом, при хорошей погоде и большом количестве спутников точность  обычно не превышает +-5 метров. Потому что эта погрешность вноситься автоматически для гражданских приборов.

Но если привлечь математику, то можно все обработать и получить приемлемые результаты. Google, который известен своими математическими алгоритмами обработки, разработал [специальную библиотеку](https://code.google.com/p/ceres-solver/) и выложил в открытый доступ. Об этом можно почитать на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143205/).

Она правда написана на с++, но либо jni, либо (что будет достаточно сложно и не производительно) переписать на java. Также есть вариант, когда клиент просто записывает набор точек, а сервер обрабатывает и усредняет. А результат отправляет клиенту.